# Tkinker Python3 Frame Update

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I have my Tkinker app where I create more frame and based on what I click I show one or another, the problem now is that I want them to refresh with new information every time that I call them; do you know how can I do?
This is my code:

```
class HFlair(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
        self.container=container

        self.frames = {}
        for F in ((StartPage, None), (PageOne, None)):
            page_name = F[0].__name__
            frame = F[0](parent=container, controller=self, attr=F[1])
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name,arg=None):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        if arg:
            frame.users(arg)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,attr=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,attr)
        self.controller = controller
        self.title=tk.Frame(self)
        self.title.pack(side="top")
        self.menu=tk.Frame(self)
        self.menu.pack(side="top")
        self.app=tk.Frame(self)   #### frame that I want refresh
        self.app.pack(side="top") #### frame that I want refresh


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, attr=None):
        self.controller=controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,attr)
        self.controller = controller
        self.title=tk.Frame(self)
        self.title.pack(side="top")
        self.menu=tk.Frame(self)
        self.menu.pack(side="top")
        self.app=tk.Frame(self)   #### frame that I want refresh
        self.app.pack(side="top") #### frame that I want refresh
```

My problem is that in the frame self.app I have some information that I take from the DB so every time that I go to this specific page I want the Frame refresh to take update information.

Is there some easy way to do it?
I try with .update() but didn't work, more than other didn't give me any issue but the Frame didn't refresh.

Comment: `update()` is used to force `mainloop` to update/redraw widgets, not to update your data. You can create in every page function `update_frame()` and call them in `show_frame` - `frame.update_frame()` - so it will be executed everytime you change page. Some pages can have empty `update_frame()`, in others you can put your code.

Comment: ottimo, non ci avevo proprio pensato ma funziona perfettamente ;) grazie 1000 :D

Comment: I don't know what you are taking - except "grazie" :)

Comment: Oh man sorry, I was trying your advice and I wrote very fast without think about the language :S lol I was saying that it's working perfectly, thanks so so much for the help ;) and if I remember very well you helped me a lot in other post ;) tks a million :D